# Drupal page caching with different versions of the cache

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

My Drupal site is very much faster with page caching on. However, I have a custom module that serves 5 different slightly different versions of my content. In other words, people in New York see East Coast stories, but not California stories, but everyone sees national stories. This is mostly done through a custom views filter that checks for a cookie.

Is there a way of serving cache A to people with cookie A, cache B to people with Cookie B, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I think [cache_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_get/7) might be useful in this case since you need dynamic data, but without cost of **complex** database queries.

Cache in this case is set via [cache_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_set/7)